# If U contains A and B, and X is 80% of A, how much percents is X in U?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's suppose that U is the universe set and it contains the sets A that is 60% of U and B that is 40% of U, so they are disjoints, the set A contains the set X that is 80% of A, how much in percent is X in U?

Comment: Why do they have to be disjoints? $A$ could be in $B$.

Comment: @Calvin All that's needed is that there is an upvoted answer that's posted in order to close as a duplicate. (Now it's upvoted once). I deleted my answer, given the duplicate post by same OP,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is $60%$ and $X$ is $80%$ of $A$, then the percent of $X$ in $U$ is $.6*.8 = .48$.

This can be thought of in terms of probabilities. For example, what is the probability of $X$ given $A$ has already happened?